# Matlab Array with Same name Name

Tags: matlab

I am writing some Matlab code that I am parsing into c++.  The C++ Looks like this:

```
ICOMPL[dataPath].Value =5;
```

How to write this in Matlab so that the syntax is similar? For example;

```
ICOMPL = [0,1,2,3];
```

Let's me do

```
ICOMPL(datapath+1) = 5;
```

But how to add the value part?  I would need that each element in the array would have the name value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that MATLAB is not C++ so not everything has to be the same, specially when you get to objects. My answer assumes that `ICOMPL` is not an object from a class, but an struct:

You can make structs in MATLAB, also arrays of structs.

A struct is as easy as

```
ICOMPL.Value= 5;
```

An array of structs:

```
ICOMPL(datapath+1).Value = 5;
```

So each of `ICOMPL` will be a whole struct. Note that you may not need this, and you may want to have

```
ICOMPL.Value= 1:5;
```

A single struct with several values on each of its elements. Often this last one is easier to work with in MATLAB. That's your decision to make.

Comment: It doesn't have to be the same but it makes the parsing into c++ easier if it is.  Can you give an example of an array of structs?  I guess I would need to name them value0, value1 etc...

Comment: @user1876942 I already gave you an example... `ICOMPL(1).Value = 1;ICOMPL(2).Value = 2;`

Comment: That works at the command prompt; but how to initialize that in code?

Comment: This did it:  repmat(struct('Value',0),1,4);

Comment: @user1876942 you dont need to initialize them, this is MATLAB. Cosnider accepting the answer if it helped ;)